# SSL Connectivity fails between corda node and artemis deployed in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, ssl, corda, activemq-artemis

We are trying to connect Corda node to a standalone Artemis server (both are deployed in kubernetes cluster) as described in the [Corda documentation](https://docs.corda.r3.com/corda-firewall-component.html#standalone-artemis-server). After starting the Corda node we get below error:

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid cert ification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1457)~[netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1365)~[netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
        ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1626)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:970) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:967) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1459)~[?:1.8.0_212]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1457)~[netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1365)~[netty-handler-4.1.29.Final.jar:4.1.29.Final]
        ... 17 more
```

Comment: Could you provide the `broker.xml` from ActiveMQ Artemis as well as the Corda config?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to our tutorials on deploy corda node via kubernetes at [Part1](https://medium.com/corda/corda-enterprise-kubernetes-deployment-part-1-of-2-efccf4ed9a25) and [Part2](https://medium.com/corda/corda-enterprise-kubernetes-deployment-part-1-of-2-efccf4ed9a25)

Most likely, you have missed some steps during the setups, and your nodes are not really even started.